# Responsive design, when jump from "desktop" design to "tablet" and so on?

Tags: html, css, layout, responsive-design

I had 3 variants of design, for desktop (1440), tablet (768) and mobile (320) and have to do responsive layout according to each of them.
In what breakpoints I have to jump from desktop to tablet and from tablet to mobile?

Comment: Use `1366px, 1360px, 1280px, 1024px, 800px, 768px, 667px, 414px, 411px, 375px, 360px, 320px`

Answer (score 0):

```
Check the below media queries for Desktop, Tablets and Laptops
@media (min-width:320px)  
{ /* smartphones, iPhone, portrait 480x320 phones */ }
@media (min-width:481px)  
{ /* portrait e-readers (Nook/Kindle), smaller tablets @ 600 or @ 640 wide. */ }
@media (min-width:641px)  
{ /* portrait tablets, portrait iPad, landscape e-readers, landscape 800x480 or 854x480 phones */ }
@media (min-width:961px)  
{ /* tablet, landscape iPad, lo-res laptops ands desktops */ }
@media (min-width:1025px) 
{ /* big landscape tablets, laptops, and desktops */ }
@media (min-width:1281px) 
{ /* hi-res laptops and desktops */ }
```